# Filter RxJava Observable with other Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm using RxAndroid 2.0.1 with RxJava 2.0.6.

I have two observables: one returns `Maybe<MyObject>` based on some String (ID). When the optional object is returned, I have to call the second one that takes the MyObject instance and returns `Single<Boolean>` if object meets some conditions. Then I can do some further operations with the object instance.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
objectDAO.getById(objectId)
    .subscribe(
        myObject -> checkCondition(myObject),
        throwable -> /* Fallback */,
        () -> /* Fallback */
    );

private void checkCondition(final MyObject myObject) {
  otherDAO.checkCondition(myObject)
    .subscribe(
        isTrue -> {
          if (isTrue) {
            // yay! now I can do what I need with myObject instance
          } else {
            /* Fallback */
          }
        },
        throwable -> /* Fallback */
    );
}
```

Now I'm wondering how could I simplify my code. My ideas:

1. Try to use `zip` - I can't because second Observable can't be subscribed until the first one returns the MyObject
2. Try to use `filter` - Now the issue is that I need to use blocking get to call second observable. It will propably work, but looks like a code smell:

   ```
   objectDAO.getById(objectId)
     .filter(myObject ->
       otherDAO.checkCondition(myObject).blockingGet()
     )
     .subscribe(
         myObject -> checkCondition(myObject),
         throwable -> /* Fallback */,
         () -> /* Fallback */
     );
   ```
3. Try to use `flatMap` - The second observable returns Boolean while I need to return the original object. Because of that I need to mape a code snippet with `blockingGet` and return original object or `Maybe.empty()`

Any suggestions how to do it in such a way that the code is "clean" (it's smaller and it's still clear what's happening inside)?

Comment: `objectDAO.getById(objectId).flatMap(myObject -> otherDAO.checkCondition(myObject).map(isTrue -> Pair.create(myObject, isTrue))` - then you have an `Observable<Pair<MyObject, Boolean>>` and can proceed however you want: subscribe directly and check the `Boolean` there, `filter` by the `Boolean` value, etc.

Comment: @david.mihola it's similar to mine 3rd method, except that now I've realized that I don't need to use blocking get. So rather that returning `Pair<Boolean, MyObject` I can check the boolean and return `Maybe.just(myObject)` or  `Maybe.empty() / Maybe.error()` Still not sure if it's a good solution.

Comment: Also, it seems I can't use `objectDAO.flatMap(otherDao.map())` combination, and when I change it to `objectDAO.map(otherDao.map())` then the result is `Single<Maybe<Pair<Boolean, MyObject>>>` which is also not so nice

Comment: Yeah, sorry - it's called `flatMapSingle`!

Comment: Yeah, I also found that I can use `flatMapSingle` instead. Now I have other issue, but not related to the original question. Please paste your full answer below so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do:

```
objectDAO.getById(objectId)
    .flatMapSingle(myObject -> otherDAO
        .checkCondition(myObject)
        .map(isTrue -> Pair.create(myObject, isTrue))
    )
```

Then you have an `Observable<Pair<MyObject, Boolean>>` and can proceed however you want: `subscribe` directly and check the `Boolean` there, `filter` by the Boolean value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersfilterasync) extra project by akarnokd has a `filterAsync` transformer (to be used with `compose`) that does just that, using a any `Publisher<Boolean>` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with solution without passing Pairs with boolean values, in case anybody will face same problem.
For example, if `objectDAO.getById(objectId)` returns `Observable<T>` and `otherDAO.checkCondition(myObject)` returns `Single<Boolean>`, we can handle filtering in such a way:

```
objectDAO.getById(objectId)
    .flatMap(myObject -> otherDAO
        .checkCondition(myObject)
        .toObservable()
        .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
        .map(o -> myObject))
    .flatMapSingle(obj -> ...)
```

Unwanted objects will be resolved to `Observable.empty` and thus filtered, so that only needed objects will get to `.flatMapSingle(obj -> ...)`

Basically, same thing can be achieved with slightly easier to understand structure (though, I've found the first one a bit nicer aesthetically):

```
objectDAO.getById(objectId)
    .flatMap(myObject -> otherDAO
        .checkCondition(myObject)
        .flatMapObservable(isChecked -> isChecked ? Observable.just(myObject) : Observable.empty()))
        .flatMapSingle(obj -> ...)
```